# Sitecore Rocks shows no template info

Tags: templates, sitecore, sitecore-rocks

I recently installed Sitecore Rocks (1.2.6.0) into Visual Studio 2012 and connected it to my existing Sitecore 6.5 instance. I can see all my objects in the master database, but when I hover over them, the "Template" value is blank, and the "Template ID" is {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}. Am I missing a step in order to get the template information into Rocks?

Comment: Did you allow it to install the "Hard Rock Web Service"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as it seems you are using the Good Old Web Service to connect to the Sitecore Service which won't provide you with template information. To resolve the issue you should start using the new Hard Rock Web Service when you try to connect to your Sitecore Instance. Keep in mind that that the Hard Rock Web Service requires .NET CLR v4.0 and Sitecore 6.5 runs on v2.0 by default. Tested this on my local and everything seems to work fine on a Sandbox Instance.